# CPython: Why does lower (string method) create new memory locations?

Tags: cpython

What's going on here?:

```
>>> a, b, c = ("TEST", "test", "TEST".lower())
>>> map(id, [a,b,c])
[140341845003072, 140341845003216, 140341845003264]
>>> map(str, [a,b,c])
['TEST', 'test', 'test']
>>> map(type, [a,b,c])
[<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>]
```

Shouldn't "TEST" and "TEST".lower() or "test" and "test".lower() share the same memory location?

**EDIT**: I get that there's a new copy, but I thought when two strings are the same, they share the same memory space, i.e.:

```
>>> a = "test" 
>>> b = "test"
>>> map(id, (a,b))
[140341845003216, 140341845003216]
>>> a is b
True
```

On Python 2.7.3, I get:

```
>>> a = "test"
>>> a is a.lower()
False
```

Comment: Python strings are immutable.  Like Java, Javascript, and Haskell.  Not like C, C++, or Ruby.  If the string is different, it *has* to have a different location in memory.

Comment: Also, note that if `x = "test"`, then `x is x.lower()` on my version of Python (3.2.3).

Comment: That was my point that the strings are the same so why do they get different addresses. It seems some of the answers below and yours re:3.2.3 are helping me approximate the implementation.

Comment: Just because two strings have the same content doesn't mean they have the same address.  In order to give strings the same address, Python would have to search *all strings in the program* to find the same string in order to reuse it, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Just imagine I gave you a copy of "War and Peace" and told you to put it in your library.  If you wanted to make sure there were no duplicate copies, you would have to search your entire library for "War and Peace", then read both books to make sure they are the same word for word.  That's a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) are clear. For `string.lower()`:

> ```
> Return a copy of s, but with upper case letters converted to lower case.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want identical strings to be identical objects, `intern` them.

By default `None, True, False` are like that; As well as constants in the source including strings, even across modules.

Answer (score 0):

That is not guaranteed to be always the case (that equal strings are always the same object). But as others have pointed out, it depends on the Python implementation (e.g. for Dietrich with CPython 3.2.3, it is the same object).

The code of CPython 2.7 is quite simple: https://github.com/albertz/CPython/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c#L1984